# dompdf form not working properly in secure server (ssl)

Tags: forms, ssl, dompdf

I created a form using dompdf and when I uploaded it to the regular server the website belongs to, it worked fine. However, when I moved it to a secure server (ssl) it didn't work and didn't send the form. The server runs Linux. The webserver is Nginx with FastCGI. Any ideas about what could be going on? I just get an error message from the form saying that not all the mandatory fields have been filled, but there's only two and I filled them.

```
2015/09/10 22:07:35 [error] 14522#0: *1509 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP 
message: PHP Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, 
array given in 
/var/www/nuweights.net/html/patient_registration_form/form.php on line 13
PHP message: PHP Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be 
string, array given in 
/var/www/nuweights.net/html/patient_registration_form/form.php on line 13
PHP message: PHP Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$prim_phone in 
/var/www/nuweights.net/html/patient_registration_form/pdf.php on line 
180" while reading response header from upstream, client: 72.83.230.123, 
server: nuweights.net, request: "POST 
/patient_registration_form/form.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "ssl.nuweights.net", 
referrer: "https://ssl.nuweights.net/patient_registration_form/form.php"
```

This is the code for the php file. If I need more validation, how can I add it? what would be the code for that?

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {

// Used for later to determine result
$success = $error = false;

// Object syntax looks better and is easier to use than arrays to me
$post = new stdClass;

// Usually there would be much more validation and filtering, but this
// will work for now.
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
$post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));

// Check for blank fields
if (empty($post->first_name) OR empty($post->last_name))
    $error = true;
else {

    // Get this directory, to include other files from
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

    // Get the contents of the pdf into a variable for later
    ob_start();
    require_once($dir.'/pdf.php');
    $pdf_html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Load the dompdf files
    require_once($dir.'/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); // Create new instance of dompdf
    $dompdf->load_html($pdf_html); // Load the html
    $dompdf->render(); // Parse the html, convert to PDF
    $pdf_content = $dompdf->output(); // Put contents of pdf into variable for later

    // Get the contents of the HTML email into a variable for later
    ob_start();
    require_once($dir.'/html.php');
    $html_message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Load the SwiftMailer files
    require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');

    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport()); // Create new instance of SwiftMailer

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                   ->setSubject('Patient Registration Form') // Message subject
                   ->setTo(array('info@hotmail.com' => 'Sam')) // Array of people to send to
                   ->setFrom(array('no-reply@net.tutsplus.com' => 'PRF')) // From:
                   ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html') // Attach that HTML message from earlier
                   ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'reg_form.pdf', 'application/pdf')); // Attach the generated PDF from earlier

    // Send the email, and show user message
    if ($mailer->send($message))
        $success = true;
    else
        $error = true;

     }

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be related to dompdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your secure server is separate from your non-secure one, correct? It looks like maybe `display_errors` (in the PHP configuration) is set to "on" for the secure server. Because of this you're seeing messages from PHP related to code notices and errors. Unless you're on a dev server you should pretty much always disable that setting to avoid information disclosure.

Before you worry about what dompdf is doing you should address the configuration issues and add some exception handling and/or validation to your code.

Some thoughts on what you've posted.

You're generally validating without regard to the data type in your `foreach` loop. You should at least check whether the variable is parseable by  `strip_slashes()`, e.g.:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
  if (is_array($_POST[$key])) {
    // assuming this is an array of values
    $post->$key = array_map('trim', array_map('strip_slashes', $_POST[$key]));
  }
  else
  {
    $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
  }
}
```

2 - You're trying to validate properties that may or may not exist on your object. Since you're not making any definite assignments you need to check that these properties even exist before you validate against them:

```
if (!property_exists($post, 'first_name') || !property_exists($post, 'last_name') || empty($post->first_name) || empty($post->last_name))
{
  $error = true;
}
```

3 - Why are you assigning properties to a generic object in the first place? If you want to use an object you should probably go ahead and define the class so that you can populate and validate the values during instantiation. If you don't want to do that assign them to variables so you know, *really know*, what data you have. If you want to short-cut it you could do something like this (or write your own):

```
$first_name = filter_var($_POST['first_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
```

To simplify this for a large number of you could even set up an array of expected params and parse that array to set your values:

```
$post = array();
foreach (array('first_name','last_name') as $key)
{
  $post[$key] = filter_var($_POST[$key], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
}
```

4 - Use curly braces for clarity ... always

You might want to take this over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get a more thorough critique.

Comment: Just as a side note: when I'm trying to debug problems with dompdf the first thing I usually do is make sure the HTML is generated correctly by taking dompdf out of the equation.

Comment: Thanks! how could I add more validation? I edited the question and added the code I have in the php file.

Comment: @SamanthaIsabel updated my answer to reflect the update to your question.